# How to convert JSON data into an array of specific data type

Tags: swiftui, stripe-payments

I have an API call that requests something that looks like this:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "acct_1MksGkPS84v9RDr2",
      "object": "account",
      "business_profile": {
        "mcc": null,
        "name": null,
        "support_address": null,
        "support_email": null,
        "support_phone": null,
        "support_url": null,
        "url": null
      },
      "capabilities": {
        "acss_debit_payments": "inactive",
        "affirm_payments": "inactive",
        "afterpay_clearpay_payments": "inactive",
        "bancontact_payments": "inactive",
        "card_payments": "inactive",
        "cartes_bancaires_payments": "inactive",
        "eps_payments": "inactive",
        "giropay_payments": "inactive",
        "ideal_payments": "inactive",
        "link_payments": "inactive",
        "p24_payments": "inactive",
        "sepa_debit_payments": "inactive",
        "sofort_payments": "inactive",
        "transfers": "inactive",
        "us_bank_account_ach_payments": "inactive"
      },
      "charges_enabled": false,
      "controller": {
        "is_controller": true,
        "type": "application"
      },
      "country": "US",
      "created": 1678640475,
      "default_currency": "usd",
      "details_submitted": false,
      "email": "anish8@gmail.com",
      "external_accounts": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/accounts/acct_1MksGkPS84v9RDr2/external_accounts"
      },
      "future_requirements": {
        "alternatives": [],
        "current_deadline": null,
        "currently_due": [],
        "disabled_reason": null,
        "errors": [],
        "eventually_due": [],
        "past_due": [],
        "pending_verification": []
      },
      "metadata": {},
      "payouts_enabled": false,
      "requirements": {
        "alternatives": [],
        "current_deadline": null,
        "currently_due": [
          "business_profile.mcc",
          "business_profile.product_description",
          "business_profile.support_phone",
          "business_profile.url",
          "company.address.city",
          "company.address.line1",
          "company.address.postal_code",
          "company.address.state",
          "company.name",
          "company.tax_id",
          "external_account",
          "representative.address.city",
          "representative.address.line1",
          "representative.address.postal_code",
          "representative.address.state",
          "representative.dob.day",
          "representative.dob.month",
          "representative.dob.year",
          "representative.email",
          "representative.first_name",
          "representative.last_name",
          "representative.phone",
          "representative.ssn_last_4",
          "tos_acceptance.date",
          "tos_acceptance.ip"
        ],
        "disabled_reason": "requirements.past_due",
        "errors": [],
        "eventually_due": [
          "business_profile.mcc",
          "business_profile.product_description",
          "business_profile.support_phone",
          "business_profile.url",
          "company.address.city",
          "company.address.line1",
          "company.address.postal_code",
          "company.address.state",
          "company.name",
          "company.tax_id",
          "external_account",
          "representative.address.city",
          "representative.address.line1",
          "representative.address.postal_code",
          "representative.address.state",
          "representative.dob.day",
          "representative.dob.month",
          "representative.dob.year",
          "representative.email",
          "representative.first_name",
          "representative.last_name",
          "representative.phone",
          "representative.ssn_last_4",
          "tos_acceptance.date",
          "tos_acceptance.ip"
        ],
        "past_due": [
          "business_profile.mcc",
          "business_profile.product_description",
          "business_profile.support_phone",
          "business_profile.url",
          "company.address.city",
          "company.address.line1",
          "company.address.postal_code",
          "company.address.state",
          "company.name",
          "company.tax_id",
          "external_account",
          "representative.address.city",
          "representative.address.line1",
          "representative.address.postal_code",
          "representative.address.state",
          "representative.dob.day",
          "representative.dob.month",
          "representative.dob.year",
          "representative.email",
          "representative.first_name",
          "representative.last_name",
          "representative.phone",
          "representative.ssn_last_4",
          "tos_acceptance.date",
          "tos_acceptance.ip"
        ],
        "pending_verification": []
      },
      "settings": {
        "bacs_debit_payments": {},
        "branding": {
          "icon": null,
          "logo": null,
          "primary_color": null,
          "secondary_color": null
        },
        "card_issuing": {
          "tos_acceptance": {
            "date": null,
            "ip": null
          }
        },
        "card_payments": {
          "decline_on": {
            "avs_failure": true,
            "cvc_failure": true
          },
          "statement_descriptor_prefix": null,
          "statement_descriptor_prefix_kana": null,
          "statement_descriptor_prefix_kanji": null
        },
        "dashboard": {
          "display_name": null,
          "timezone": "Etc/UTC"
        },
        "payments": {
          "statement_descriptor": null,
          "statement_descriptor_kana": null,
          "statement_descriptor_kanji": null
        },
        "payouts": {
          "debit_negative_balances": true,
          "schedule": {
            "delay_days": 2,
            "interval": "daily"
          },
          "statement_descriptor": null
        },
        "sepa_debit_payments": {}
      },
      "tos_acceptance": {
        "date": null
      },
      "type": "standard"
    },
```

It looks like that but like 10 more times.

It is an array of a dictionary of the type `User`:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var id: String
    var email: String
    
    //... more, but these are just the most important
}
```

here is my existing code:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let result = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
        accounts = [result]
    } catch {
        print("Failed to decode JSON: \(error)")
    }
```

And here is the error that I was getting:

```
Failed to decode JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

How do I turn all of that JSON data into an array of `User`s. Also how do I fix that error too?
Any and all help is appreciated :)

Comment: To `...turn all of that JSON data into an array of User`, copy and paste your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/  this will generate all your models for you. Or you can do it by hand, matching the models properties to the json data.

Comment: Thank you so much, this saved me so much time! Would you like to post an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `...turn all of that JSON data into an array of User`, copy and paste your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/ this will generate all your models for you.

Here is my test code, given the `let json = .....the json data`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var users = [User]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(users) { user in
            VStack {
                Text(user.country)
                Text(user.email)
                Text(user.businessProfile.name ?? "no name")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            do {
                // simulated data from an API
                let data = Data(json.utf8)
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data)
                users = decodedResponse.data
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
//        .task {
//            await loadData()
//        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://......") else {
            print("URL Failed")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data)
            users = decodedResponse.data
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct ApiResponse: Codable {
    let object: String
    let data: [User]
}

struct User: Identifiable, Codable {  // <-- here
    let id, object: String
    let businessProfile: BusinessProfile
    let capabilities: Capabilities
    let chargesEnabled: Bool
    let controller: Controller
    let country: String
    let created: Int
    let defaultCurrency: String
    let detailsSubmitted: Bool
    let email: String
    let externalAccounts: ExternalAccounts
    let futureRequirements: Requirements
    let metadata: Metadata
    let payoutsEnabled: Bool
    let requirements: Requirements
    let settings: Settings
    let tosAcceptance: DatumTosAcceptance
    let type: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, object, capabilities, controller, country, created
        case requirements, settings, metadata, email, type
        case businessProfile = "business_profile"
        case chargesEnabled = "charges_enabled"
        case defaultCurrency = "default_currency"
        case detailsSubmitted = "details_submitted"
        case externalAccounts = "external_accounts"
        case futureRequirements = "future_requirements"
        case payoutsEnabled = "payouts_enabled"
        case tosAcceptance = "tos_acceptance"
    }
}

// MARK: - BusinessProfile
struct BusinessProfile: Codable {
    let mcc, name, supportAddress, supportEmail: String?
    let supportPhone, supportURL, url: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mcc, name, url
        case supportAddress = "support_address"
        case supportEmail = "support_email"
        case supportPhone = "support_phone"
        case supportURL = "support_url"
    }
}

// MARK: - Capabilities
struct Capabilities: Codable {
    let acssDebitPayments, affirmPayments, afterpayClearpayPayments, bancontactPayments: String
    let cardPayments, cartesBancairesPayments, epsPayments, giropayPayments: String
    let idealPayments, linkPayments, p24Payments, sepaDebitPayments: String
    let sofortPayments, transfers, usBankAccountAchPayments: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case acssDebitPayments = "acss_debit_payments"
        case affirmPayments = "affirm_payments"
        case afterpayClearpayPayments = "afterpay_clearpay_payments"
        case bancontactPayments = "bancontact_payments"
        case cardPayments = "card_payments"
        case cartesBancairesPayments = "cartes_bancaires_payments"
        case epsPayments = "eps_payments"
        case giropayPayments = "giropay_payments"
        case idealPayments = "ideal_payments"
        case linkPayments = "link_payments"
        case p24Payments = "p24_payments"
        case sepaDebitPayments = "sepa_debit_payments"
        case sofortPayments = "sofort_payments"
        case transfers
        case usBankAccountAchPayments = "us_bank_account_ach_payments"
    }
}

// MARK: - Controller
struct Controller: Codable {
    let isController: Bool
    let type: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isController = "is_controller"
        case type
    }
}

// MARK: - ExternalAccounts
struct ExternalAccounts: Codable {
    let object: String
    let data: [String]  // <-- here ?
    let hasMore: Bool
    let totalCount: Int
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case object, data
        case hasMore = "has_more"
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case url
    }
}

// MARK: - Requirements
struct Requirements: Codable {
    let alternatives: [String]  // <-- here ?
    let currentDeadline: String?
    let currentlyDue: [String]
    let disabledReason: String?
    let errors: [String]  // <-- here ?
    let eventuallyDue, pastDue: [String]
    let pendingVerification: [String]  // <-- here ?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case alternatives, errors
        case currentDeadline = "current_deadline"
        case currentlyDue = "currently_due"
        case disabledReason = "disabled_reason"
        case eventuallyDue = "eventually_due"
        case pastDue = "past_due"
        case pendingVerification = "pending_verification"
    }
}

// MARK: - Metadata
struct Metadata: Codable {
}

// MARK: - Settings
struct Settings: Codable {
    let bacsDebitPayments: Metadata
    let branding: Branding
    let cardIssuing: CardIssuing
    let cardPayments: CardPayments
    let dashboard: Dashboard
    let payments: Payments
    let payouts: Payouts
    let sepaDebitPayments: Metadata

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dashboard, payments, payouts, branding
        case bacsDebitPayments = "bacs_debit_payments"
        case cardIssuing = "card_issuing"
        case cardPayments = "card_payments"
        case sepaDebitPayments = "sepa_debit_payments"
    }
}

// MARK: - Branding
struct Branding: Codable {
    let icon, logo, primaryColor, secondaryColor: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case icon, logo
        case primaryColor = "primary_color"
        case secondaryColor = "secondary_color"
    }
}

// MARK: - CardIssuing
struct CardIssuing: Codable {
    let tosAcceptance: CardIssuingTosAcceptance

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tosAcceptance = "tos_acceptance"
    }
}

// MARK: - CardIssuingTosAcceptance
struct CardIssuingTosAcceptance: Codable {
    let date, ip: String?
}

// MARK: - CardPayments
struct CardPayments: Codable {
    let declineOn: DeclineOn
    let statementDescriptorPrefix, statementDescriptorPrefixKana, statementDescriptorPrefixKanji: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case declineOn = "decline_on"
        case statementDescriptorPrefix = "statement_descriptor_prefix"
        case statementDescriptorPrefixKana = "statement_descriptor_prefix_kana"
        case statementDescriptorPrefixKanji = "statement_descriptor_prefix_kanji"
    }
}

// MARK: - DeclineOn
struct DeclineOn: Codable {
    let avsFailure, cvcFailure: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case avsFailure = "avs_failure"
        case cvcFailure = "cvc_failure"
    }
}

// MARK: - Dashboard
struct Dashboard: Codable {
    let displayName: String?
    let timezone: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case displayName = "display_name"
        case timezone
    }
}

// MARK: - Payments
struct Payments: Codable {
    let statementDescriptor, statementDescriptorKana, statementDescriptorKanji: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statementDescriptor = "statement_descriptor"
        case statementDescriptorKana = "statement_descriptor_kana"
        case statementDescriptorKanji = "statement_descriptor_kanji"
    }
}

// MARK: - Payouts
struct Payouts: Codable {
    let debitNegativeBalances: Bool
    let schedule: Schedule
    let statementDescriptor: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case debitNegativeBalances = "debit_negative_balances"
        case schedule
        case statementDescriptor = "statement_descriptor"
    }
}

// MARK: - Schedule
struct Schedule: Codable {
    let delayDays: Int
    let interval: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case delayDays = "delay_days"
        case interval
    }
}

// MARK: - DatumTosAcceptance
struct DatumTosAcceptance: Codable {
    let date: String?
}
```